# Vagrant is creating files and folders in my project

Tags: puppet, vagrant

Recently I updated Vagrant (v 1.6.3) and I noticed that in the folder of my project there are some new folders and files like:

```
d20140610-11944-1j6n1cz/
d20140610-15421-1pkz3t8/
vagrant20140610-11944-p76ezc
vagrant20140610-11944-p76ezc2
vagrant20140610-11944-yt3bhz
vagrant20140610-11944-yt3bhz1
vagrant20140610-15421-mfqrig
vagrant20140610-15421-mfqrig1
vagrant20140610-15421-y3r71a
vagrant20140610-15421-y3r71a2
vagrant20140610-15421-y3r71a2.lock
```

most of the files are empty, others have text like this:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
source "http://gems.hashicorp.com"
gem "vagrant", "= 1.6.3"
group :plugins do
gem "vagrant-login", nil, {}
gem "vagrant-share", nil, {}
end
```

The directories have a file named **config** with this this info:

```
BUNDLE_PATH: "/home/user/.vagrant.d/gems"
```

Is this some kind of debug option? how can I disable it?

Comment: You may have more luck reporting this at https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @sciurus suggested I asked that on GitHub and this I the answer I got:

> The issue is a permissions thing on your temp folder on your system.
>   We're going to add detection for this in an upcoming version of
>   Vagrant.

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/4020#issuecomment-45929445

Answer (score -2):

"Vagrant is creating files and folders in my project"

Simple solution:

```
chown root.diego /tmp
chmod 1777 /tmp -R
```